# Should I delete a question which was caused by a typo but yet could be useful!

Tags: discussion, questions, typographical-error, deletion

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975808/button-doesnt-work-when-there-is-a-float-attribute) in which I asked why an HTML button doesn't work in the presence of `float` attribute in its style or its container style. After some try, I realized that in the container style I missed colon (:) for another attribute (padding). Now, I don't know, should I delete this question, or write my finding as an answer! because, anyway that typo results in the problem where the button doesn't respond and interestingly it occurs when the `float` exists and not always!!!

By the way, if I had posted the exact code, maybe someone could notice that typo!

Comment: Doesn't sound like it would be useful to anyone else. Just delete it.

Answer (score 4):

If the question isn't all that good, there's no shame in deleting it.

You state that the problem boils down to a typo, and that you didn't have the full code posted so it was more readily apparent to yourself and others.  Those kinds of questions aren't likely to be helpful to anyone else, and would only inspire downvotes for you, so deleting it is a good idea.

Comment: Right! but I wonder why such a typo cause that strange behavior when the `float` exists and maybe an expert could explain that! However, I agree that wouldn't be easy to interpret the web browser mechanism.